# Im writing a shell script and need to combine "find", and "grep" inside of a "if then" statement

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have been working on a Script that automatically changes my Macbooks wallpaper based on the currently connected SSID. and it will select a new wallpaper every 30min

Long story short it's working fine, but im trying to create the illusion of "randomness" by not allowing the script to repeat the same wallpapers too often.

The command to pull a wallaper currently looks like this;

```
find -E -L ~/WallAware/A -type f -regex ".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)" \( -atime +5 -o -mtime -1 \) | ~/WallAware/gshuf -n 1
```

Which I mistakenly thought would work.

So what I need to do is:

1. use find to get a random file from a folder with an access time of 5+ days (This will prevent wallpapers being repeated too often)
2. If there is no file with an access time of 5+ days, then get a file with a modified time of -1 (This will prioritize new wallpapers if all other have been seen in the last 5 days)
3. If it cant do either of those then just pick a random file.
4. put the path to the selected wallpaper in the variable "$B"

I am very much still learning, I am [documenting my progress over at Github](https://github.com/relink2013/WallAware) for fun.

Comment: Seems like a good plan. Did you check that just tje`find` command is working? Edit your Q to include an explanation of what `gshuf -n 1` is supposed to do. Comments: 1) once you get your command to work, then you can use  `B="$(find ... )" ; echo "B=$B"` 2). In your current `find` your case 3 will not happen. You may be able to add another `-o ...something` inside the `\( ..\)` that would get your random file, but I think it make more sense to just display all files and have something else that will pick one at random (`gshuf -n 1`?). Maybe that is your intent with current code. Good luck.

Comment: Why not just write the date & time and name of wallpaper displayed to a log file. You can then just `grep` the name of the wallpaper in the logfile and then parse the date & time to check how long ago it was displayed. To choose a wallpaper, why not just use the number you have in the dir and then select the `$(($RANDOM % no_of_wp))` one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

my_find() {
    find -type f '(' -false $(for ext in png jpg gif jpeg; do echo "-o -name *.$ext"; done) ')' "$@"
}

if my_find -atime +5 -print -quit | grep .; then
    B=$(my_find -atime +5 | shuf -n 1)
elif my_find -mtime -1 -print -quit | grep .; then
    B=$(my_find -mtime -1 | shuf -n 1)
else
    B=$(my_find | shuf -n 1)
fi

# then do your stuff with B
```

Feel free to replace `shuf` by `gshuf` if you are on Mac OS X. I am not sure `find` on Mac OS X will have all these options though. `-quit` is optional. Also you could put extensions in a variable (`$exts`).

Edit: [from this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/89522):

> The difference? Spotlight doesn't index /tmp, but it does index ~. I'm pretty sure that what you're seeing here is spotlight reading the file to index it after you change the atime - which then sets the atime back to now.

I believe this could be your atime issue. Otherwise atime should work just fine on Darwin. You could either add your path to exceptions, or use a path not indexed by Spotlight (`/wallpapers` could work).

Comment: Hmmm, this doesnt seem to be working as expected. Could totally be my fault too.

Im now just cycling the latest 6 images, probably because they are the only 6 with a mtime of less than 1 day.

I tried changing the atime to +1 instead of +5, and it didnt change anything.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I believe macOS is using mtime as the atime. I changed both commands to mtime and lowered the first condtion from 5 to 1, and its working. if I increase the condtion up 30days (which there are no files this old), then it begins cycling through only the most recently accessed. 

What is macOS doing differently? atime, mtime, and ctime, dont seem to correlate to whats displayed in finder? if I use "touch -a" then in finder it shows the modified time changed, when it should have changed the access time.

Comment: Just edited my post with a Spotlight-related problem, and gave instructions on how to fix that.